# Text_Diff pear package installation (Shared Hosting)

Tags: php, installation, pear, cpanel

I'm using some shared hosting (linux server) and would like to know how to set up Text_Diff the pear package.

Is it possible to setup without command line access?.. (I have cPanel access)

Link: [Text_Diff](http://web.archive.org/web/20080506115821/http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff/)

Answer (score 1):

The [PEAR Text Diff package](http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff/) doesn't have any 'external' dependencies so this should be easy enough.

1. Download the .tgz from http://pear.php.net/package/Text_Diff/download - click on the Download link ;)
2. Decompress that .tgz to anywhere on your computer
3. Upload the extracted files to be inside the include_path on the
   remote host.
4. To see what your include path is, just use something like echo get_include_path(), "\n";

Recommended Reading: [Installation of a local PEAR copy on a shared host](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/installation.shared.php)